# SubscriptionClient.AcceptMessageSession Faiiled with Timeout exception

Tags: azure

I created a Azure Topic and a subscription with Session-Enabled to be true.  I can send a message to the topic with a non empty SessionId.  But When I tied to read the message with the following code, it throws the timeout execption at subClient.AcceptMessageSession.  Did I do anything wrong?  The similar code (with QueueClient) works fine for a direct session enabled Azure Queue.

```
SubscriptionDescription subscriptionDescription = namespaceManager.GetSubscription(Topic_Name, Subscription_Name);
SubscriptionClient subClient = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, Topic_Name, Subscription_Name);

if (subscriptionDescription.RequiresSession)
{
    msgSession = subClient.AcceptMessageSession(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
    if (msgSession != null)
    {
        message = msgSession.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
else
    message = subClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```